# Set /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS on executable target

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to create a solution for VS 2019 that contains two targets with one *CMakeLists* file. That is not the problem. My problem is: one is a console application and the other one a gui app and both need different linker options.

For the gui project it is no problem:
`set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")`

But if i add the other executable i cannot get it managed to set the subsystem to console.

I even tried to set the linker options explicit for the target

`set_target_porperties(hexToArray [BEFORE] CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE")`

but it doesn't work either. The subsystem is still "Windows".

Is there any possibility to achieve what i want to do?

Comment: You override the linker flags variable, so the "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS" is the first one that gets found.

Have you tried not overriding the flag or restoring it afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS is global, don't change that.

For the GUI target, simply do:

```
add_executable(TheGuiTarget WIN32 Gui.cpp ...)
```

or set the [WIN32_EXECUTABLE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html#prop_tgt:WIN32_EXECUTABLE) property on TheGuiTarget afterwards.

The console target should receive `/subsystem:console` by default.